# How to integrate a Spring WEB application with a Spring Data REST application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-integration, spring-data-rest

I have a purpose.

I want to integrate a **Spring WEB application** *"ApplicationWeb"* with a **Spring Data Rest** application *"ApplicationRest"*, in a way that I can propagate the Spring Security context of *"ApplicationWeb"* to the *"ApplicationRest"* (If I make the login in "ApplicationWeb" with user *"user1"*, the "ApplicationRest" have to know that the Principal logged is "user1").

Furthermore, I want that the URLS of the "ApplicationRest" will be accessible **only FOR and FROM** the "ApplicationWeb" application.

How can I configure the two applications properly?

What's the best kind of integration I can use?

I know that the question is very generic, but I'm interested in some solutions that can make possible this kind of implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used Spring Security in these applications?

Comment: Certainly, I have use Spring Security for "ApplicationWeb".

Comment: And your requirement is to just have the Spring Security Integration and ApplicationRest accessibility restrictions?

Comment: My requirement is to have the Spring Security integration between the two applications, and a way to make the interaction between them: for example, I want to read the REST datas from the REST application passing by the Web application (with channels or some other kind of integration)

Comment: 1 more q - are they both deployed in the same container?

Comment: For now, yes, there are deployed both on the same servlet container, it's only a test for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of items that I assume you already have done in your projects, for example user configuration, preauth filters etc. So I am only listing those items which you have to specifically do to get the integration done.

Here is what you have to do to get the Spring Security integration possible.

1. Bring up a database (any relation database is fine)
2. Apply the schema in this [gist](https://github.com/nareshbafna/oauth2/commit/51c97ba2c44ec245e3d93a6fed909f38ebc8f00e)
3. Configure the datasource in your application. See the gist again for XML configuration.
4. Modify the InMemoryTokenStore to look for JdbcTokenStore instead.
5. Use ApplicationWeb as your authorization-server
6. Use ApplicationRest as your resource-server
7. Use the same resource-id for both the authorization and resource server.
8. When calling the resource server, pass the token which is already generated using `/token` endpoint in ApplicationWeb (auth-server), in the `Authorization` header.

Regarding the request filtering, as long as they are both in the same container and CORS is not supported, the requests must fail. But in case you want to absolutely limit the possibility of any other client / bot attacking ApplicationRest

1. Use a custom header in the requests from ApplicationWeb to ApplicationRest. Why I propose a custom header is that, standard HTTP Headers can be manipulated or mirrored easier than a custom header.
2. Use a standard Servlet filter in your ApplicationRest to allow or reject any ill requests.

If you require more information on the Spring Security, I suggest you do a bit of googling first and if you find no luck , let me know, I can post more detailed instructions when I get some time.

Comment: Thank you very much aksappy for your response, I'll try to do this like as your suggest.